# Delete lines containing a given string at different positions in different files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

As an example below, let's say the line I want to delete contains the string `"X"`. How do I delete that line in each respective file, say, in a loop? Can I do this using `grep` and `sed`, or any other shell/bash program for that matter?

```
Line  File 1  File 2
   1       A       A
   2       B       B
   3       X       C
   4       C       X
   5       D       D
   6       E       X
   7       X       E
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you want to simple remove a line which has character "X" in it then this Simple `grep` command to rescue here:

```
grep -v "X"   Input_file
```

Adding `sed` solution too now, which will change Input_file itself:

```
sed -i.bak '/X/d'  file*
```

Comment: You could mention something on how to use `grep` to change an existing file.

Comment: @Alfe, apologies if missed something here, but I am not aware of any option where `grep` could save the changes in file itself, please do let me know if there is any, always open for learning :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Use `sed` for inline saving: `sed -i.bak '/X/d' file`

Comment: `grep` indeed doesn't have such an option (except maybe in some weird system's variant of `grep`, I surely don't know all of them).  But you always can redirect its output in a new file and later rename that to the original (`grep -v "X" Input_file > x && mv x Input_file`).  I had the feeling OP was searching for this.

Comment: @anubhava, sure sir you mean `sed -i.bak '/X/d'  file*` since OP told many files are there :)

Comment: @Alfe, sure Alfe but that could be good for 1 Input_file for multiple we may have to take different approach too or please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Thank you! :) I completely overlooked the grep -v command here. And yes, @Alfe you're right. I was thinking of redirecting outputs to another file and do the process recursively. Thanks all! :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The solution with grep would handle one file, right.  You can then put it inside a loop to process more than one file.  That approach is called "Separation Of Concerns".